# Dependence of current in electronvolts

Tags: electromagnetism, energy, definition

Definition: 1 eV  is when an electron passes  through  a potential difference of 1 V  and gains/loses energy.

1. Where  is  this potential difference? Is it between  two plates in a apparatus setup?
2. Is this potential  difference  and applied voltage to the  experimental  setup/circuit,  are they two different things?
3. If the device used  to create  a  potential difference of 1  V used  a  power  of  1  watt  and 1 ampere  current, then  can we define  1 eV as being the  energy  gained  by  electron when it passes  through a  electric field  using 1  watt  power using 1  ampere current?

I am not  sure if my third  question makes  sense. If you  could  help  me with corrections or clarification, that would be great.

Comment: electron volt (eV) is a convenient unit of energy - $1\rm eV = 1.6\cdot 10^{-19} J$. Power is a rate of energy (1 W = 1 J/s). Not clear if that is what you need to resolve your confusion... if it is not, please clarify your question.

Comment: It is very slightly better now - I hope that Bill N's answer works for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your definition is not accurate. One electron-volt is an energy unit *equivalent to the amount of energy* gained (or lost) by one electron accelerated across a potential difference of 1 V. What you have stated is simply a result of the acceleration, not the definition of the electron-volt. Plus, we should be even more general and instead of using the electron, we should use a particle with a charge of 1 electronic unit, e.

The acceleration of an actual electron doesn't have to happen. Nor does there actually have to be a potential difference. Those are merely concrete items which are used to define an equivalent amount of energy. The mass energy of an electron is approximately 511,000 electron volts, but there doesn't have to be any potential of 511,000 volts for the electron to exist.